# I want to append sudo infront of any command via script

Tags: linux, scripting, sudo

I want to add sudo infront of every command(like the title says) but I don't want to make sudo - i / sudo su -

I want that you enter a "sudo mode" but you can keep working like a normal user.

So I can perfectly implement my /etc/sudoers file in my system.

I had following idea: (its a concept not finished it has many flaws i dislike but maybe it helps to get an idea):

```
#!/bin/bash

prompt:"sudo mode prompt>" 

while : ; do
read -e -p "$prompt" command
$(sudo $command) 
done
```

I don't like that variant so do you know some scripts/programs?

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you want to achieve :

```
#!/bin/bash

prompt="sudo mode prompt>" 

while : ; do
    read -p "$prompt" -r command
    sudo bash -c "$command"
done
```

Comment: Hello Philippe - i am happy you try to contribute. I have one problem and that is that the bash completion wont work with that method. Thats why i used "read - e" sadly it wont autocomplete commands like systemctl via tab nor will i get the last command i used with the up arrow. I am using suse as os. - KR Daniel

Comment: Take a look at https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap